# Rosdep Melodic vs Kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, ros-kinetic, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have `<depend>python-rpi.gpio</depend>` dependency in my package and `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y` works fine in Kinetic since it installs rpi-gpio with `sudo -H pip install -y python-rpi.gpi` command but it fails in Melodic with the error:

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
    apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-gpiozero] failed
    apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-gpiozero]
```

because it tries to do `sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rpi.gpi`

Is there any way to make rosdep install use pip in Melodic or there is another way to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337001/rosdep-melodic-vs-kinetic/) by [Tonу](https://answers.ros.org/users/48999/ton%D1%83/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know *why* this is the case, but I can explain how `rosdep` decides to use `apt` on Bionic while it uses `pip` on Xenial.

If we look at [ros/rosdistro/rosdep/python.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/41d315986b2cae9274b168ef672834f0e24fa462/rosdep/python.yaml), which is where `rosdep` gets its information about how to map *keys* to actual packages, we see this for the `python-gpiozero` key (from [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/41d315986b2cae9274b168ef672834f0e24fa462/rosdep/python.yaml#L1724-L1754)):

```
python-gpiozero:
  ...
  ubuntu:
    ...
    bionic: [python-gpiozero]
    ...
    xenial:
      pip:
        packages: [gpiozero]
    ...
```

we can clearly see that for `xenial`, the `pip` installer is requested, while for `bionic`, only the package name is listed, which will make `rosdep` use the default installer for that OS, which would be `apt`.

It looks like these keys were added in [ros/rosdistro#16544](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/16544),which initially used `pip` for everything, but based on a comment by @tfoote changed to `apt` for some OS.

The package does exist according to `packages.ubuntu.com` ([here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-gpiozero)), but I also get `Unable to locate package python-gpiozero` trying to install it using `apt`.

I would suggest to figure out why that is the case, instead of trying to force the use of `pip` (which would be impossible, short of changing the key for `python-gpiozero`).

---

Edit: ah, I overlooked the available architectures listed on [packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-gpiozero](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-gpiozero). It looks like that package is only available for `arm64` and `armhf`. I'm trying this on `amd64`, so it would make sense for `apt` not being able to find it. `pip` does not check these sort of things, so it will happily install anything, anywhere (which may then still fail).

Are you running `rosdep` on `arm64` or `armhf`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonу](https://answers.ros.org/users/48999/ton%D1%83/) on 2019-11-07**:
Yes, thank you, I was trying to run it on  `amd64`